# Axios API call on window/browser close

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios

I know there is already a lot of discussion about this topic but I still haven't found an solution. I've found quite some answers saying that it is not quite possible so I am looking for an alternative on how to handle this correctly.

For the context I am using Vue with Pinia store and Axios for my API calls.
In the backend we have a so called "lock system" which makes sure that only one person at a time can edit a certain object in the database.

The problem I have now is that I want to execute a method from my Pinia store with an axios API call IF the user closes the window/browser. It is an important API call which makes sure to delete any possible locks so other users can work on the object.
The timeout for the lock is set to 2 hours so for example if the user is editing something and suddenly closes the window the object stays locked for another 2 hours.

We do have the option for other users to force the lock and kick the other user out of editing the object, but that is meant only for rare cases and I would ideally like to avoid it in this situation.

I have tried stuff along the lines:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.returnValue = ''
  store.deleteLocks()
})
```

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
  if (document.visibilityState == 'hidden') {
      store.deleteLocks()
  }
})
```

I guess the closest I got was probably the following:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
  store.deleteLocks()
})
```

But since its an async function its not getting run correctly.

So noting works quite as expected.
Anyone has any idea how to smartly handle this or work around it?

Comment: Ditch Axios for this, and use the Beacon API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API

Comment: The method I am sending is DELETE I guess Beacon API only does POST requests or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it supports only POST. But you should still consider switching, because you don't get that "reliability" regarding execution of using other means of making a request.